# How do I read a Minecraft crash log to determine the root of the issue?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-mods

So I'm trying to help a friend join a modded Minecraft server with me. things would load in well and she would appear in game, but then after 5 minutes the game would crash and spit out a crash report. I looked into it, tried to reach out to some technical friends, the server host, and the main modpack forums but we are unable to figure out the main issue.

I'm not well versed into reading logs or digging into files but I have a little experience of having to open files with notepad++ or running/fixing servers for particular games.

We did some general "fixing" (allocating memory, reinstalling the modpack, etc.), but none of it solved the issue.

I'm pretty stuck at the moment; here's the log report.

https://gnomebot.dev/paste/1134265097347420210

I would *really* love to learn how to read crash errors and logs out of curiosity, why it was written in such a way. I got as far as to trying to learn how one person in a different website used the return call and a range of numbers in the dynamic tree to determine it was a graphical issue in some java-script for something random. I would love to get the experience to learn how java-scrip works and one day even help others with their Minecraft issues.

Comment: For those casting close votes: this is not supporting modded minecraft - this is understanding the crash log. It is not specific to mods.

Comment: I would just like to point out that JavaScript is a completely different language from Java. (Minecraft being written in Java, JavaScript being what typically runs in the browser.)